# How to pass a local list of lists to a global outside outside function? And how can i check if csv file DNE or is empty?

Tags: python, csv, global, local

I know that moving the information in the file_open into global would fix my issue but my professor insisted that I move it all that code into a function which is why I'm having problems.

```
def file_open():
  my_data = open('vgsales.csv')
  data = csv.reader(my_data)
  data_list = list(data)
  my_data.close()

def year_release_count()->None:
  """
  Tells the user how many games in a specific
  year was released 
  """
  count = 0
  year = input("Enter Year: ")
  for index in range(len(data_list)):
    if(data_list[index][3] == year):
      count += 1
  print(count)

def info()->None:
    print("Which function would you like to run?")
    print("Enter 1, to see the number of games released in specific year")
    value = int(input("Enter: "))
    if(value == 1):
       year_release_count()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  file_open()
  info()
```

Comment: You can use `return` to return data from a function, and so you could so something like:
`data = file_open()` to get the data from your `file_open` function and add a `return data_list` to your `file_open` function would allow it to return that data.

Comment: can you show error?

Comment: @Stephen Thank you man <3 that was so simple I don't know why I didn't think of that.